# How to orient objects to face towards another object in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, particles, geometry-nodes, hair

I have set up a particle system based on a group of people that I would like to face towards a target.

I know I can play with the rotation of the whole system and randomize, but global rotation doesn't quite work if the target were to be in the center of the particle system.

Also, I know that I can bake the particles and add a track-to-constraint, but baking thousands of high poly meshes would make the file unusable. So, looking to see if there is a way to keep the particle system and orient towards a target.

**Edit: With geometry nodes this has become significantly easier. See  answer below**

[image]

Comment: "*I know that I can bake the particles and add a track-to-constraint, but baking thousands of high poly meshes would make the file unusable*" What do you mean "bake" the particles? You can make duplicates real, keeping instances, and it shouldn't be much heavier than the current setup, while allowing adding the necessary constraint. That sounds like the way to go

Comment: I mean converting the particle system to real geometry. They share mesh data, but in my experience Blender doesn't handle thousands of objects well. Once I do bake, I have thousands of objects and blender slows down significantly. It's not usable for the number of particles I am working with - 7000-15,000.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [crowdmaster](https://github.com/johnroper100/CrowdMaster) or [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/)

Comment: Thanks @sambler for the suggestion. I've looked into crowdmaster, but it looks quite complicated, and it doesn't rely on a particle system, meaning that if there are thousands of objects, Blender significantly slows down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Geometry Nodes, having instances that face a particular object like an empty has become significantly easier. Here is the setup

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Use a Force Field:

Hair particles, even without using dynamics, follow the force fields:

[image]

In the Viewport do *Add* > *Force Field* (type "*Force*"). Place it where you need it to be. From the *Physics* properties panel, set the force to a negative value and leave the rest as it is.

The internal rotation of the base hair particle (humans) must be adjusted to make sure that the correct side points to the Force Field. In my case this is the mesh used:

[image]

Note that the "face" is looking towards negative Z, while the "head" is "up" in the direction of positive Y. The correct rotation must either be achieved in edit mode or obtained in object mode and then applied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*)

You need neither the "*Advanced*" setting on Emission, nor the "Rotation" extra settings.